# Shallow copy interfaces

Tags: golang

Можно ли копировать интерфейс так же как структуры ?

```
type MyInterface interface{}
myInterface2 := *myInterface
```

Сейчас ошибка `invalid indirect of`

Comment: непонятно чего ты хочешь добиться? какая задача то?

Comment: Вопрос в том, почему оператор ( := ) не работает с переменной типа интерфейс. Если у меня переменная типа MyInterface и я хочу сделать копиию через := но это не работает. Но если создать : type MyType struct{} и написать : myStruct2 := myStruct то это работает.

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/vCEWqVuDh5 но очевидно, что ты хочешь чего то другого и не понятно чего =)

И учти, что interface{} это "ссылочный" тип, при его копировании ты создаешь лишь новую ссылку на объект на который указывает этот интерфейс

Comment: Кажется я понял. При `myInterface2 := *myInterface` компилятор не знает что значит разыменовать (*) интерфейс, тк это не ссылка, но ты можешь ему указать явно что за тип там лежит `var myInterface2 interface{} = myInterface.(myType)`

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/JfZ9oSTfWD

Comment: а разыменовать? `myType := *(myInterface2.(*MyType))` https://play.golang.org/p/0tvHvbAx_w

Comment: Если не знаешь имплементацию - определи конкретные интерфейсы для работы с любой имплементацией и пользуйся ими, приводить тип к этим же интерфейсам.

Comment: Если типы имеют что-то общее то да. Но у меня одно поле только одинаковое у всех типов (обькеты модели дб  таблиц). Где только проперти (firstName, lastname, age i т.д.) и больше не чего

Comment: Тогда зачем тебе делать копию того, что ты не знаешь как выглядит и, соответственно, не знаешь как с этим можно работать? Посмотри как сделан стантартный database/* пакет. Хотя твой случай больше похож на encoding/json.Marshaller/Unmarshaller

Answer (score 1):

При `myInterface2 := *myInterface` компилятор не знает что значит разыменовать (*) интерфейс, тк это не ссылка, но ты можешь ему указать явно что за тип там лежит

```
var myInterface2 interface{} = myInterface.(myType)
```

Если и тип тебе не известен, то только reflect сможет тебе помочь, но он медленный и ведет к большому кол-ву ошибок =)

https://play.golang.org/p/W43YP7MGSU

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type MyStruct struct {
    N int
}

type MyInterface interface{}


func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
    var my_struct_1 MyInterface = MyStruct{N: 1}
    var my_struct_2 MyInterface = my_struct_1.(MyStruct)

    fmt.Println(my_struct_1, my_struct_2)

    t := reflect.TypeOf(my_struct_1)
    fmt.Println(t)

    ss2 := reflect.ValueOf(my_struct_1).Convert(t)
    fmt.Println(ss2)    
    fmt.Printf("%T %#v\n", ss2, ss2)

    // Увы он останется reflect.Value типом, пока, опять же, не сделаешь явное преобразование ss2.Interface().(MyStruct)

    ss2_MyStruct := ss2.Interface().(MyStruct)
    fmt.Printf("%T %#v\n", ss2_MyStruct, ss2_MyStruct)
}
```

Comment: Рефлексия не подходит: медленно. Я понял что компилятор не знает о типе и без явного приведения типов копирование работать не будет. Решу через switch instanceof